# Why is my output completely different because of a simple printf command?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I was practicing recursion and i came up with this rather meaningless formula. I was inputting random numbers to check my code. After few tries code did not output anything so i assumed that there might be infinite loop somewhere in my function so i added ***printf("*");*** in the middle of a function. But after that output was asterisk and some number. Can someone please explain why i am not getting number output without asterisk and getting one when asterisk is present?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isPrime(int n)
{
    if(n<2)return 0;
    int p;
    while(p<n){
        if(n%p==0)return 0;
        p++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int f(int n)
{
    if(n%2==1&&n>56)return n;

    else {
        int i, r=0;
        printf("*");            //This is the controversial asterisk
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            if(isPrime(i))r+=i;
        return f(r);
    }
}

int main(void){

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if(n<0)n=-n;
    printf("%d", f(n));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please check the compiler warnings: `int p;` has not been initialised, and the code has *undefined behaviour*. Adding a random `printf` changes the value that might be inherited by `p`.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal that unfortunately does not change anything

Comment: You must set `p` to the initial value required. Here is a better use case of `for` than of `while`.

Comment: Even if you assumed `int p;` would make it 0, the prime check would be wrong (`n % 1 == 0` for all `n`).